# git-svn: commit whole history of an existing git repository into an empty Subversion sub-directory

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

I've been working on some code locally on my computer, tracking modifications using git (no remote).
That code is now to become a module in a larger project, the code base of which is stored in Subversion (so something like `https://svnserver/svnroot/project/trunk/module_x`), so I thought I could use git-svn to manage the Subversion repository as a remote. I remember doing that before for another project but could not find the modus operandi (changed computers in-between).

Here is what I tried:

```
cd ~/mygitrepo/
git svn init https://svnserver/svnroot/project/trunk/module_x
git svn fetch
git svn rebase
```

The last command yields the following error message:

```
Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history
```

I read somewhere that it might be because the directory was empty in Subersion so I tried committing a dummy file to SVN separately then ran:

```
git svn fetch
    A   dummy.txt
r10744 = 89294ba713c6fed368f3b879c8dc7744b1015308 (refs/remotes/git-svn)
```

However, I cannot find the `dummy.txt` file in my git repo and both `rebase` and `dcommit` will  continue to show the same error message.
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer provided by Jan gives the rationale for the error I encountered and points to plain old `git rebase --onto` as the proper solution but lacks the actual commands.

I initially proposed those commands as an edit to his answer but it was rejected, so here goes:

```
git checkout -b svnrebase git-svn            # create a temporary branch
git cherry-pick master~1                     # cherry pick the first  commit
git rebase --onto svnrebase master~1 master  # rebase the 2nd through current commit
git svn dcommit                              # finally commit the results to svn
```

**NOTE** that `master~1` must be changed to reference your first commit to the git master. Here, we suppose we have a git repo with just two commits.

It is necessary to create a temporary branch and cherry-pick the first commit to master because `rebase --onto` only rebases the range of modifications made *after* `master~1` (and the `master~2` reference would not exist with just two commits).

Answer (score 2):

Your checked out branch does not come from subversion, so `git svn` does not know how to work with it.

Git does, however, so what you need to do is use plain `git rebase` to rebase onto `git-svn` (`refs/remotes/git-svn`). Then the history will contain commits coming from subversion and `git svn dcommit` will know where to commit it.

Another thing is that your changes need to be placed in correct subdirectory *before* you try to rebase them, because `git rebase` does not support moving into subdirectory. `git merge` does, via the `subdirectory` strategy, but using merge will export to Subversion as a single commit. If you want to export full history, and you don't have it in correct directory *in all commits*, you will have to use `git filter-branch` to fix it up.

Comment: Thanks for providing the rationale and pointing me to the right direction, e.g. `git rebase --onto`. I edited your answer to add the actual commands sequence because rebasing the initial commit onto git-svn isn't too trivial and it might help somebody else.

Comment: Edit was rejected so I will answer my own question instead.